# Migrar un WordPress a localhost

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, localhost

estoy tratando de hacer una copia de un WordPress que esta se encuentra publicado, hago la copia de MySQL y la cargo a mi PhpMyAdmin y estoy haciendo una copia de todo el contenido de la carpeta `public_html` y la coloco en la carpeta de proyectos (`htdocs`).

Si inicio el proyecto en este punto me menciona:

> Error al establecer una conexión con la base de datos

Hago la configuración debida de la conexión de base de datos en el archivo `wp-config.php` pero si inicio el proyecto nuevamente me menciona el navegador que:

> No se puede acceder a este sitio

Desconozco si tengo que hacer una configuración o simplemente la copia la tengo que realizar de otra manera, me podría ayudar.

Comment: lo que pasa es que toda la configuración que se realizó en el momento de la instalación aún está presente. Busca una guía de migración de WP para que veas los archivos que tienes que modificar, y pueda funcionar de forma local en tu pc.

Comment: Revisa el apartado **Manually Move a Live WordPress Site to Local Server** de [este enlace](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-live-wordpress-site-to-local-server/) y verifica si has hecho todo como se indica allí. Ahí se explica cómo migrar tu sitio de forma manual (no es tan complicado como parece, lo puedes hacer sin tener que recurrir a un plugin). Puede que te hayas saltado alguna etapa y por eso no te funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Como ya bien dice el comentario de [@DavElsanto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/30750/davelsanto), debes realizar otras configuraciones adicionales tanto a nivel de codigo fuente como a nivel de base de datos.

Una opción bastante fácil de migrar o reproducir tu sitio en local es el siguiente [plugin](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/)

El cual permite generar un archivo zip el cual debes colocar en tu localhost y luego realizar los pasos que te solicita para replicar. Es muy fácil de usar.